# Swift - swipe recongiser and swiping an object

Tags: swift

my code shows a blue object that covers the entirety of the screen. On swipe, the object is thrown into that particular direction. Is there a function or an if statement that once the object leaves the screen the exact same object is respawned to be swiped again? Happy to provide more info if this post is too vague.

```
import UIKit



class ViewController: UIViewController {



@objc private func didSwipe(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    // Current Frame

    var frame = swipeableView.frame



    switch sender.direction {

    case .up:

        frame.origin.y -= 1000.0

    case .down:

        frame.origin.y += 1000.0

    case .left:

        frame.origin.x -= 1000.0

    case .right:

        frame.origin.x += 1000.0

    default:

        break

    }

    
//  following is an attempt at respawning the object



   let actionforrespawn = self.swipeableView.frame = frame

   let respawnObjectOnCompletion = self.swipeableView.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero

   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: actionforrespawn, completion: respawnObjectOnCompletion)

}



}



private func createSwipeGestureRecognizer(for direction: UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction) -> UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

    // Initialize Swipe Gesture Recognizer

    let swipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didSwipe(_:)))



    // Configure Swipe Gesture Recognizer

    swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = direction



    return swipeGestureRecognizer

}







private let swipeableView: UIView = {

    // Initialize View

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero,

                                    size: CGSize(width: 800, height: 1000)))



    // Configure View

    view.backgroundColor = .blue

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false



    return view

}()



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Add to View Hierarchy

    view.addSubview(swipeableView)



    // Create Swipe Gesture Recognizers

    swipeableView.addGestureRecognizer(createSwipeGestureRecognizer(for: .up))

    swipeableView.addGestureRecognizer(createSwipeGestureRecognizer(for: .down))

    swipeableView.addGestureRecognizer(createSwipeGestureRecognizer(for: .left))

    swipeableView.addGestureRecognizer(createSwipeGestureRecognizer(for: .right))

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `UIView.animate` function, so that object respawns after animation is complete. Here is an example:

```
        let action = self.swipeableView.frame = frame
        let respawnObjectOnCompletion = self.swipeableView.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
        
        UIView.animate.(withDuration: 0.25, animations: action, completion: respawnObjectOnCompletion)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I edited the code to what you mentioned and I get two errors. I have updated the code in the post to what you said. What can i do to make it work 
?  Cheers.

Comment: @jecboncraig Hi, can you provide an error description?